# don't understand the difference between "gcc -c file.c" and "gcc -o file.c" command

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, execution

### Command :

```
`gcc -c -Wall hello.c`
```

### Here is the error : while calling *./hello.o*

```
bash: ./hello.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

need help please ..

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: `-c` Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link. You can find all infos [HERE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

Comment: `hello.o` is not an executable file.

Answer (score 0):

.o is an object file, not an executable. It's an intermediate step. The -c option just says to make that step. You'll still have to link that object file into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

These are the options you are asking for

> `-c`
>
> **Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.** The linking stage simply is not done. The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.
>
> By default, the object file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix ‘.c’, ‘.i’, ‘.s’, etc., with ‘.o’.

Unrecognized input files, not requiring compilation or assembly, are ignored.

> `-o file`
>
> Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>
> If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.

Using the first option you will have an object file, not an executable so you cannot execute it